# "Внутрях", "в нутра́х", или "в нутрях"?

Tags: общие-вопросы

«Данные хранятся в массиве в нутрях интерпретатора»

Это нормально? Учитывая, что

1. есть другое слово:
   НУ́ТРИ, нескл., м., и НУ́ТРИЯ, и, ж. (зоол.). Субтропическое животное из породы грызунов, водяная крыса, с ценным мехом.
   Источник: «Толковый словарь русского языка» под редакцией Д. Н. Ушакова (1935-1940)
2. есть правило: “слитно пишутся наречия, которые образованы от прилагательных с помощью приставки и суффикса”.
3. если "в нутра́х" то слова несогласованы, должно было бы использоваться слово "интерпретаторов" (т.е. во множественном числе).

если "внутрях" это наречие, то от какого прилагательного оно образовано?

Answer (score 0):

Внутрях - это одна из форм наречия внутри. Такие наречия пишутся слитно. Без приставки "в" такого слова не существует. Отличайте от существительного с предлогом "в нутре", есть слово "нутро". Что до наречия внутри, то оно возникло путем слияния двух слов: предлога вън и существительного утръ в форме местного падежа утри.